# BufferedReader in Python 2.x vs Python 3.x

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, bufferedreader

I have a program that runs in Python 2 and Python 3, but there is a drastic difference in speed. I understand a number of internal changes were made in the switch, but the difference in io.BufferedReader are really high. In both versions, I use io.BufferedReader because the main program loop only needs data one byte at a time. Here is an excerpt from the cProfile output for the script (see **cumtime**, not tottime):

```
Python 2:
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 36984   0.188    0.000    0.545    0.000   io.py:929(read)

Python 3:
 36996    0.063   0.000    0.063    0.000   {method 'read' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
```

When I print the object, both return something like `io.BufferedReader` so I am certain they are both using BufferedReader.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/uFc4g2pq) is the code in question. See line 28. The caller is responsible for setting up bufstream. I used `bufstream = io.open('testfile', 'rb')`

Why is there such a drastic difference in speed of BufferedReader for reading single bytes in the files, and how can I "fix" the issue for Python 2.x? I am running Python 2.6 and Python 3.1.

Comment: Ok good. So what's the question?

Comment: @Eric: Based on your edit, does performance matter that much for you?

Comment: @A A , Yes the performance is quite important, which is why I am asking how to fix the problem. In the best case scenario, throughput 525 KB/s on both versions of Python but in a more typical scenario, Python 2 throughput is 59KB/s while Python 3 comes in at 155KB/s.

Comment: @Eric: All right then, given the figures, I hope someone answers your question.

Comment: @Eric Pruitt: About your edit 2, what is the constructor arg `stream`?

Comment: Eric, why do you read 1 byte at a time? Could you read chuncks and `yield` 1 byte at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give you a fuller answer, one would need to see your code (or, better, an executable precis of your code).

However a partial answer can be gleaned from your profile output: `io.py` suggests that "Python 2" (for avoidance of doubt, give the actual version numbers) is implementing BufferedReader in Python, whereas `_io.BufferedReader` suggests that "Python3" is implementing it in C.

Late-breaking news: Python 2.6's `io.py` is over 64Kb and includes the following comment up the front :

```
# This is a prototype; hopefully eventually some of this will be
# reimplemented in C.
```

Python 2.7's `io.py` is about 4Kb and appears to be a thin wrapper of an `_io` module.

If you want real assistance with a workaround for 2.6, show your code.

**Probable workaround for Python 2.6**

Instead of:

`test = io.open('test.bmp', 'rb')`

do this:

```
test = open('test.bmp', 'rb')
```

**Some rough timing figures**, including the missing link (Python 2.7):

Windows 7 Pro, 32-bit, approx 5 Mb file, guts of code is:

```
while 1:
    c = f.read(1)
    if not c: break

2.6: io.open 20.4s, open 5.1s
2.7: io.open  3.3s, open 4.8s # io.open is better
3.1: io.open  3.6s, open 3.6s # effectively same code is used
```

So a better story seems to be this: In general, don't faff about with io.open unless you have good reason to e.g. you want 2.7 to go faster.

Comment: The code is just a call to io.BufferedReader.read(1). The number of times I have to call .read(1) varies, but I only handle one byte at a time.

Comment: @John It's up to the caller to open the stream. The call was in Kabie's post that you replied to. In this case it's a one liner: `test = io.open('test.bmp', 'rb')`

Comment: @Eric Pruitt: The general idea is to edit your question with such info so that answerers don't have read all the comments on every other answer when trying to help you. See my updated answer.

Comment: @John, understood. I thought it was intuitive that I was using io.open, but I have updated my original question. That seems to have done the trick. I do not know if it is from past experience with Python 2.5 (which is what I was using the most until I upgraded to Debian Squeeze Beta 2 a several days ago), but I had it in my mind that reading bytes one by one was really slow in Python. Using plain open increased throughput on Python 2.6 and Python 3, albeit a tiny amount on the latter. Thanks!

Comment: Throughput is now ~102KB/s on Python 2.6 and 160 KB/s on Python 3.1.

Comment: @Eric Pruitt: That seems funny, since `open is io.open` in Python 3.1.

Answer (score 4):

Using 2.7 should solve this. See [PEP 3116](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/#buffered-i-o) and [Python 2.7 doc](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3116-new-i-o-library).

[A part of module io is written in python](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release26-maint/Lib/io.py?revision=83588&view=markup&sortby=rev&sortdir=down) in 2.6, while in 2.7+ [the whole module is written in C](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c?view=markup&sortby=rev&sortdir=down)

Comment: What does StringIO have to do with this? I'm just using BufferedReader on a file; io.open(filepath, buffering=...).

Comment: `StringIO` has absolutely nothing to do with the OP's problem.